Why did Kaworu put on the DSS Choker?
In Evangelion: 3.0 You Can (Not) Redo, Shinji is forced to wear a DSS Choker. He's told the collar will kill him if he tries to pilot an Eva. Kaworu is able to remove the collar, only for him to then put the collar on himself. Later near the end of the movie:

 the collar explodes and kills Kaworu.

Why did Kaworu put on the collar after taking it off Shinji?
